# Is there any good maildir mail notifier for GNOME3?

Tags: email, gnome, gnome3, maildir

I'm looking for a maildir capable mail notifier, a'la biff/xbiff, but for GNOME3. I found [this](http://bluezoo.org/gnome-biff/), but it gets its settings from Evolution, and I am not using Evolution - I'd simply like it to watch the maildirs I download with offlineimap.
The ability to launch my mail client (gnome-terminal + mutt) via a click would also be nice.

I'm using GNOME 3.16.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is not directly what you asked for, you should take a look at "Geary", it is an official Gnome App for E-Mail, It works really nicely and is integrated with Gnome.